# Using observer, how to get the current pager with loaded product collection

Tags: collection, category, event-observer, pager

Using an observer how can i get the current pager block with its loaded product collection on a category page?

I want to check the total number of pages on a category page before it is loaded.

Answer (score 4):

You could try listening to the event `core_block_abstract_to_html_before` and then checking if the block given is of instance `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Pager`.

This block has a function `getCollection` which would give you the current collection and the function `getPages` which will give you an array of all the page ids.

```
public function coreBlockAbstractToHtmlBefore(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
    $block = $observer->getBlock();
    if($block instanceof Mage_Page_Block_Html_Pager) {
        $collection = $block->getCollection();
        $pages = $block->getPages();
    }
}
```